# Save Text Size Preferences

Tags: android, textview, sharedpreferences, font-size

I have created a custom zoom for my 'TextViews' so the user can zoom in and out. I wanted to hold the position of the zoom so next time they come in the app they wont need to zoom in again. I was wondering what the best way to do that is? Thanks.

I have 2 methods

get text size:

```
    private void getTextViewSize() {
    boolean gotTextViewsize = false;
    boolean gotDocumentViewsize = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (linearLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView) {
                (prefs.edit().putFloat("textViewSize",((TextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(i)).getTextSize())).commit();
            gotTextViewsize = true;
        }else if(linearLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof DocumentView){
            (prefs.edit().putFloat("documentViewSize",((DocumentView) linearLayout.getChildAt(i)).getDocumentLayoutParams().getTextSize())).commit();
            gotDocumentViewsize = true;
        }

        if(gotDocumentViewsize && gotTextViewsize){
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This gets the size of the text view which is called after every zoom.

Next is set text size:

```
  private void setTextSize() {

    for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (linearLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ((TextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(i)).setTextSize(prefs.getFloat("textViewSize", 15.0f));
            } else {
                ((TextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(i)).setTextSize(prefs.getFloat("textViewSize", 14.0f));
            }

        }else if (linearLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof DocumentView){
            ((DocumentView) linearLayout.getChildAt(i)).getDocumentLayoutParams().setTextSize(prefs.getFloat("documentViewSize", 15.0f));
        }
    }
}
```

This should put the size just how it was
however, it makes much much bigger than it was. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Use SharedPreferences. They are retained across activity kills and until the user clears the app data.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref");
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putInt("zoomLevel",yourZoomLevel);
```

when retrieving use:

```
yourZoomLevel=editor.getInt("zoomLevel",0);
```

Comment: I did that, please check the updated code however, it still does not work.